# Unable to run Laravel Browser Test with Dusk

Tags: laravel-5.7, php-7.2, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I am setting up Browser Test with Laravel 5.7. Install Laravel Dusk. My very beginning `php artisan dusk` command return errors

My Chrome is version 76. Initially, I see "Chrome version must be between 70 and 73". So I download Chrome Driver for my corresponding browser version. Then Run the command again, and I see a new error `Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnrecognizedExceptionException: invalid argument`

I didn't change any code after running initial `php artisan dusk:install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some interesting Issues on Github that should be your problem.

https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/651

I think that is a problem with the Driver. Perhaps you can find a solutions and check some of the mentioned problems in that issue to find your problem. It's bit difficult to help you without having the code and having the same problem to test.

Some of them have reinstalled dusk and it was working. So you can test do install the newest driver first and then install the dusk package after that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure host and Dusk are using the same Chromium driver:

```
# linux box
chromium-browser --version

# install specific version on dusk
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 78
```

I was running dusk through homebrew and I found that I needed to reload vagrant as well:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped in my case where I received an error **Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87** (I had chromium-browser 86 installed, but driver version 87)